# Cant index document with multipolygon field in elasticsearch 1.3 but works in 1.0 - NoSuchMethodError: com.spatial4j.core.shape.jts.JtsGeometry

Tags: elasticsearch

Works perfectly in 1.0.3, however when i upgrade to 1.3.1 i'm not able to index the 'location' field and it gives a NoSuchMethodError.

If i switch back to 1.0.3 it works again.

This is the document that i'm trying to index

```
{
  "location" : { "coordinates" : [ [ [ [ 0.44340355238491003,
                51.447780163517997
              ],
              [ 0.86259117505726002,
                51.180082750148003
              ],
              [ 1.0082709471378,
                50.816892583551997
              ],
              [ 0.84721779622765003,
                50.456505242372998
              ],
              [ 0.42802525366600003,
                50.194415245157998
              ],
              [ -0.13716299999998999,
                50.098842883365002
              ],
              [ -0.70235125366599005,
                50.194415245157998
              ],
              [ -1.1215437962276,
                50.456505242372998
              ],
              [ -1.2825969471376999,
                50.816892583551997
              ],
              [ -1.1369171750574001,
                51.180082750148003
              ],
              [ -0.71772955238489999,
                51.447780163517997
              ],
              [ 0.44340355238491003,
                51.447780163517997
              ]
            ] ] ],
      "type" : "multipolygon"
    },
  "modified" : 1388708645,
  "text" : "My profile"
}
```

The field mapping for location looks like this:

```
'location' => [
    'type'      => 'geo_shape',
    'tree'      => 'quadtree',
    'precision' => '1m'
],
```

The stacktrace during indexing in 1.3.1 is:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:555)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:483)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareIndex(InternalIndexShard.java:397)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:191)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:527)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:426)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.spatial4j.core.shape.jts.JtsGeometry.<init>(Lcom/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry;Lcom/spatial4j/core/context/jts/JtsSpatialContext;ZZ)V
        at org.elasticsearch.common.geo.builders.ShapeBuilder.jtsGeometry(ShapeBuilder.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.geo.builders.MultiPolygonBuilder.build(MultiPolygonBuilder.java:76)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.GeoShapeFieldMapper.parse(GeoShapeFieldMapper.java:234)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeObject(ObjectMapper.java:549)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:491)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:534)
        ... 8 more
```

and in 1.0.3 it works perfectly